# Node - Mysql Transaction is not rolling back if one query fails

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to perform node-mysql transaction which has three query in total. All three are 'INSERT' queries. I intensionally write third query wrong to test rollback but transaction is making entry to database without fail for first two queries.

I know similar question has already been asked several times and I tried almost all of them but no luck

```
exports.registerNewUserTransaction = async (
  res,
  userToBeAdded,
  nameToBeAdded,
  emailToBeAdded)  => {
  const conn = await db.getConnection();
  await conn.beginTransaction();
  try {
    await this.insertOne('user', userToBeAdded);
    await this.insertOne('name', nameToBeAdded);
    await this.insertOne('email', emailToBeAdded);
    await conn.commit();
    res.status(200);
  } catch(err) {
    await conn.rollback();
    res.status(400);
  } finally {
    await conn.release();
  }
};
```

As you can see I am getting connection object from Pool, beginning the transaction and performing queries one by one. My third query has wrong column name, hence transaction should rollback but I see entry of first two queries. I would really appreciate the correct direction.
node version: 12.8.0
mysql (running in docker): 8.0.15
mysql (npm version): 2.17.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a lot, finally figured it out. Here's the answer:

```
exports.registerNewUserTransaction = async (
  res,
  userToBeAdded,
  nameToBeAdded,
  emailToBeAdded)  => {
  const conn = await db.getConnection();
  // My first mistake was not to promisify connection query 
  conn.query = util.promisify(conn.query);
  await conn.beginTransaction();
  try {
    // My second mistake was not to use same connection
    await conn.query('INSERT INTO ...', userToBeAdded);
    await conn.query('INSERT INTO ...', nameToBeAdded);
    await conn.query('INSERT INTO ...', emailToBeAdded);
    await conn.commit();
    return res.status(200);
  } catch(err) {
    await conn.rollback();
    return res.status(400);
  } finally {
    await conn.release();
  }
};
```

Hope this might help someone!

Answer (score 0):

This is important part I missed.
conn.query = util.promisify(conn.query);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).